# Add package references to webapi in .net core

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core

net core environment. I m creating .net core webapi project in visual studio project. I am following https://github.com/allebb/lk2.git project to get hands on with .net core. when i open this solution in visual studio i can see lot of packages installed in dependencies tab as below.

[image]

same way i created solution in visual studio 2017 and i got

[image]
I can see many packages compared to the sample solution. How can i add all those reference in my test project? Parallel i have setup ubuntu environment with core 2.0 setup. But i am missing many packages in my test project! May i know how can i those missing packages? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: just for people to understand what all to explain, how new are you to .net frameworks?

Comment: I have worked in .net for 2 years. .net core and Linux is totally new to me. Thanks

Comment: ok then, .net core uses a very clean csproj file compared to the other .net framework. A lot less scary to look at and has a lot of the answers you are looking for. Also check out the CLI for using linux https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These packages are commonly used for database connections and serializing. They are quite popular and you are quite likely to use them once you start creating web applications. There are couple of ways to add them as nuget packages.

1. Right click on your project and go to "manage nuget packages"
2. Open the package manager and enter the code `install-package package.name`
3. open command prompt and add the code `dotnet add package package.name`

For more information you can look up nuget.org. 
If you want exactly the same libraries, the quickest way is open the csproj file of the git https://github.com/allebb/lk2/blob/master/lk2-demo.csproj and copy the whole `<ItemGroup>` section that contains the `PackageReference`. Then you can right click on your project and go to restore nuget packages.

To restore the projects via command line (what you can use in linux)

```
dotnet restore
```

**Update**:
Since most nugets seem to be of an older version. The quickest would be to copy the references as they are and update all nugets from the nuget manager in one go.

Comment: Thanks i added itemgroup in my csproject. Now i can see yellow mark near those references. Also i am using .net core 2.0 so instead of Version="1.1.1" i should add Version="2.0.0" right?

Comment: ok i just noticed his project is 1.1 which is an older version. chances are most other nugets are outdated too. let me update the answer to this

Comment: update all nugets from the nuget manager in one go so to perform this is there any command?

Comment: not sure if there is a command to update them all but you can use the nuget package manager > updates tab > check all and select update

Comment: by the way .net 2.0 has a package called `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` which already contains all the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.x` packages.

Comment: Finally i got error in ubuntu.  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (TestRest.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'
  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
    aspnetcore-store-2.0.3.xml
This means i need to add anti forgery reference as well. Correct right?

Comment: I just pulled the repo and simply tried `dotnet run` and it runs well. however you can try `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery`